# Writing to kerberosed hdfs using python | Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, hdfs, webhdfs, pyhdfs-client

I am trying to use python to write to secure hdfs using the following lib [link](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Authentication part:

```
def init_kinit():
    kinit_args = ['/usr/bin/kinit', '-kt', '/tmp/xx.keytab',
                  'kerberos_principle']
    subp = Popen(kinit_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    subp.wait()
```

client/upload part:

```
from hdfs.ext.kerberos import KerberosClient
client = KerberosClient(url='http://xx.com:port', session=session,
                            mutual_auth="REQUIRED")
client.upload(
        f'/hdfspath/file.parquet',
        f'/localpath/file.parquet')
```

here is the error

```
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='xxx', port=xxx): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/user/xxx/xxx.parquet?op=LISTSTATUS (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f499c104d30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I tried the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085876/hadoop-failed-to-connect-to-hdfshadoop-using-python) and I made sure that dfs.webhdfs.enabled is enabled

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that we are using https policy, changes the port & protocol and it worked just fine

```
<property>
<name>dfs.http.policy</name>
<value>HTTPS_ONLY</value>
</property>
```

code

```
client = KerberosClient(url='https://xx.com:port', session=session,
                            mutual_auth="REQUIRED")
```